# Any custom/third party Visual C# text box Controls with extra features?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program that uses the textbox in visual C# to read a log file. When dealing with very large amounts of text, writing to the textbox is incredibly slow. The textbox also lacks many features. Are there any custom textbox controls that are faster, or even a sort of embedded editor (with ability to highlight certain words, indent, input bookmarks)? Many of the features I want are programmable, but it would be nice if there was a faster textbox or one that already had these features :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) and its [.Net wrapper](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty, but most of the good ones are expensive. [Telerik](http://telerik.com) and [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com) offer .Net control libraries with lots of extended features.

Comment: All of the vendor components (Except DevExpress XtraRichEdit) wrap the standard textbox control and will not help.